# Asp.net Core Authorize Redirection Not Happening

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to use cookie authentication in an Asp.net core app (dnx 4.5). Note that because I have a custom authentication mechanism (radius), I am not using the out-of-the-box mechanism provided by core Authentication. When the user is not authenticated I want to redirect to a login page.

I have added in Startup.cs the following code. The idea is to be redirected to the Login Controller when the user has not been authenticated:

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(options => { options.LoginPath = new Microsoft.AspNet.Http.PathString("/Login"); });
```

In my Home controller I have:

```
[Authorize]
public IActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}
```

In my Login controller I return a view corresponding to the radius login form:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public IActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}
```

However, when I run the app, the redirect never happens. Looking at the console output I see the following:

```
warn: Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerActionInvoker[0]
      Authorization failed for the request at filter 'Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Filters.AuthorizeFilter'.
info: Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.ChallengeResult[1]
      Executing ChallengeResult with authentication schemes ().
info: Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Infrastructure.MvcRouteHandler[2]
      Executed action ThingsProjectorWeb.Controllers.HomeController.Index in 0ms
info: Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting.Internal.HostingEngine[2]
      Request finished in 0.0016ms 401
```

Any help on how to configure this correctly would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

OK figured it out. It is all explained here: https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/security/authentication/cookie.html

I was missing the `options.AutomaticChallenge = true;`, which automatically redirects you to the Login Controller.

Here is the updated options:

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(options => {
                options.LoginPath = new Microsoft.AspNet.Http.PathString("/Login");
                options.AutomaticChallenge = true;
            });
```

**UPDATE:**

As of version `1.1.0` it's:

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
         LoginPath = new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.PathString("/Account/Login"),
         AutomaticChallenge = true
});
```

Comment: This doesnt work for me on IISIntergration. On Kestrel I get a perfect 302 but on IIS I get a 401. Is there anything you did to make it work on IISIntergration aswell?

Comment: @MitchDart It could be that IIS is defaulting to FormsAuthentication. Try adding  <modules>
      <remove name="FormsAuthenticationModule" />
      <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
    </modules> to the web config?

Comment: This doesn't work for me either. Stuck on trying to redirect for two days now.  Do you need to add a service before this?  I have: services.AddSession(); which should add support for this.  Getting tired of Core already.  It just doesn't work.