# ASP.NET 5 Policy-Based Authorization Handle Not Being Called

Tags: c#, asp.net, authorization, asp.net-core

Following the docs here I tried to implement a policy-based auth scheme. http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/security/authorization/policies.html#security-authorization-handler-example

I ran into the issue that my Handle method was not being called on my custom AuthorizationHandler. (It does not throw here). It also does inject the dependency currently in the constructor.

Here it the AuthorizationHandler Code.

```
using WebAPIApplication.Services;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Authorization;

namespace WebAPIApplication.Auth
{
    public class TokenAuthHandler : AuthorizationHandler<TokenRequirement>, IAuthorizationRequirement
    {
        private IAuthService _authService;

        public TokenAuthHandler(IAuthService authService)
        {
            _authService = authService;
        }

        protected override void Handle(AuthorizationContext context, TokenRequirement requirement)
        {
            throw new Exception("Handle Reached");
        }
    } 

    public class TokenRequirement : IAuthorizationRequirement
    {
        public TokenRequirement()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

In Start Up I have

```
// Authorization
            services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationHandler, TokenAuthHandler>()
                .AddAuthorization(options =>
                {
                    options.AddPolicy("ValidToken",
                        policy => policy.Requirements.Add(new TokenRequirement()));
                });
```

The controller method is

```
// GET: api/values
        [HttpGet, Authorize(Policy="ValidToken")]
        public string Get()
        {
            return "test";
        }
```

Hitting this endpoint returns nothing and there is a warning in the console of

```
warn: Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerActionInvoker[0]
      Authorization failed for the request at filter 'Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Filters.AuthorizeFilter'.
```

I am able to hit other endpoints that don't have the attribute successfully.

SOS,
Jack

Comment: Same problem. Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Yes and I answered below, it falls inline with your comment on adem's comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to this question is alluded to in a comment to adem caglin, so props to him.

The issue is that the `AuthorizeFilter` is rejecting the request before the `AuthorizationHandler` is being called. This is because for every use of the `Authorize` tag  MVC adds `AuthorizeFilter` ahead of the `AuthorizationHandler` in the pipeline. This `AuthorizeFilter` checks to see if any of the current users identities are authorized. In my case there were no authorized identities associated with any user so this would always fail.

A solution (which IMO is somewhat hackish) is to insert a peice of middleware that will get executed before any MVC code. This middleware will add a generic authenticated identity to a User (if the user does not already have one).

Consequently the `AuthorizeFilter` check will pass and the `Handle` method on the `AuthenticationHandler` method will be executed and our problem will be solved. The middleware code (which needs to be added to `Configure` before `app.UseMvc();` is called) is as follows

```
    app.Use(async (context, next) =>
    {
        if (!context.User.Identities.Any(i => i.IsAuthenticated))
        {
            context.User = new ClaimsPrincipal(new GenericIdentity("Unknown"));
        }
        await next.Invoke();
    });
```

An alternative way to override the `AuthorizeFilter` is outline here ([Override global authorize filter in ASP.NET Core MVC 1.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35825021/override-global-authorize-filter-in-mvc-6/35863514#35863514))

Citing the response from here ([Asp.Net Core policy based authorization ends with 401 Unauthorized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37276005/asp-net-core-policy-based-authorization-ends-with-401-unauthorized))

Answer (score 24):

I'm putting this here for reference because I spent way too long figuring this out...

I had implemented a custom requirement and handler (empty for testing's sake):

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public class TestHandler : AuthorizationHandler<TestRequirement>, IAuthorizationRequirement
{
    protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, TestRequirement requirement)
    {
        context.Succeed(requirement);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}

public class TestRequirement : IAuthorizationRequirement
{

}
```

Registered it in my `Startup.cs` `ConfigureServices()` section:

```
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("Test", policy => policy.Requirements.Add(new TestRequirement()));
    // Other policies here
}
```

Added it to my controller method:

```
[HttpGet]
[Authorize(Policy = "Test")]
public IActionResult Index()
{
    Return View();
}
```

But was getting a 403 error (not 401) with every request to the controller method!

Turns out, I was not registering `TestHandler` with the `ConfigureServices()` (Dependency Injection) section of `Startup.cs`.

```
services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationHandler, TestHandler>();
```

Hope this saves someone from banging their head on their desk. :|

Comment: Fixed it for me. As much I love the inclusion of DI in AspNetCore it is sometimes confusing what you have to register and how.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out, I also did the same mistake. Hope, .NetCore will return some rutime error instead of 403 in future.

Comment: I just spent two days on this issue, and it turns out this is the answer I needed... and I feel like an idiot.

Comment: thanks, I was ready to switch to another implementation, but found this post at the last minite

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Asp.net Core Authorize Redirection Not Happening](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36967426/asp-net-core-authorize-redirection-not-happening) i think adding `options.AutomaticChallenge = true;` solves your problem.

Comment: I think that might be specific to cookieAuthentication. When I call `services.AddAuthorization()` I get an instance of `AuthorizationOptions` which doesn't have an `AutomaticChallenge` field

Comment: which authentication middleware do you use?

Comment: If you use `[Authorize]` attribute without authentication, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37276005/asp-net-core-policy-based-authorization-ends-with-401-unauthorized

Comment: I think that may be it. I'm using JWT authentication on most of my routes but the route I'm using a custom `[Authorize]` attribute on doesn't require a token. So that default `AuthorizeFilter` must be rejecting the request. I'll look into it tomorrow