# Asp.Net Core custom authorization always ends with 401 Unauthorized

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-security

I am trying to implement a custom Authentication/Authorization flow with asp.net core but fails to do so. The authentication seems to work ok: if I debug step by step I can see that an AuthenticationTicket is created from a ClaimsPrincipal that contains an identity with isAuthenticated to true:

```
public class MyAuthHandler : AuthenticationHandler<MyAuthOptions>
{
    protected override Task<AuthenticateResult> HandleAuthenticateAsync()
    {
        // grab stuff from the HttpContext
        string authHeader = Request.Headers["Authorization"];
        // do some stuff that are successfull in my tests
        var cp = DoTokenBasedAuthentication(authHeader);

        var ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(cp,
            new AuthenticationProperties(), Options.AuthenticationScheme);
        return Task.FromResult(AuthenticateResult.Success(ticket));
    }
}
```

However, I try to add a dummy AuthorizationHandler after that:

```
public class MyRequirement : IAuthorizationRequirement
{
    public MyRequirement()
    {
    }
}

public class MyAuthRequirement : AuthorizationHandler<MyRequirement>
{
    protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, MyRequirement requirement)
    {
        context.Succeed(requirement);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

And with this code in my startup file:

```
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
   options.AddPolicy("My",
      policy => policy.Requirements.Add(new MyRequirement()));
});
```

But whenever I add "[Authorize("My")]" on a controller, then all calls always returns 401. And my AuthorizationHandler is never reached.
This problem looks similar to [Asp.Net Core policy based authorization ends with 401 Unauthorized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37276005/asp-net-core-policy-based-authorization-ends-with-401-unauthorized) but is slightly different as on my case I have a user that is authenticated. I am struggling to debug into asp.net MVC source code, so I do not really know what is going on.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your authorization handler doesn't appear to be plugged in.
You can try to add the following line to your `Startup.ConfigureServices` method :

```cs
services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationHandler, MyAuthRequirement>();
```

Comment: Wow... I am amazed, I would never have thought that was an issue as nothing is complaining. Thank you so much !

Comment: And the IAuthorizationHandler init, must be before AddAuthorization else it cause problems too.